# Color picker in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I want to implement color picker in angular JS and below is the sample,

http://screencast.com/t/A7q6rTN5e

Can anyone suggest how to implement this in angular js?

Comment: I'd probably make an array that had the name of the icon file I wanted to use for each color button and then the color settings for that particular color, render the buttons with an ng-repeat and respond to the click of each button by setting the color.  If this is something you plan to use in multiple places then it's a good candidate for a directive.

Comment: @MikeFeltman : Can you explain this with sample code

Comment: Yeah, your question is way too broad. You're not asking for help, you're asking for someone to do your work for you. Make an attempt, ask for specific help on the issues you have trouble with.

Answer (score 1):

By your given screenshot

[image]

It can be like this.

```js
angular.module('eek', []).directive('pick', function(){
    return function(_, e) {
        e.find('td').on('click', function(){
           document.body.bgColor = this.bgColor
        })
    }
})
```

```css
body{width:100%;height:100%}td{width:30px;height:30px;border:1px solid #fff}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<table ng-app=eek>
  <tr pick>
    <td bgcolor="google"></td>
    <td bgcolor="microsoft"></td>
    <td bgcolor="instagram"></td>
    <td bgcolor="jeffatwood"></td>
    <td bgcolor="crazy"></td>
    <td bgcolor="chucknorris"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Instead of hardcoding the value in bgcolor can we set this in controller

Comment: yes, why not.,and use ng-repeat for that